# How to apply css to table rows

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I need to apply background color to the alternating rows of my html table.

My current code:

```
.licList
    {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .licList th
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #dbdbdb;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
        padding: 4px 5px;
    }

    .licList td
    {
        padding: 4px 5px;
    }

    .odd
    {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .odd td
    {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cef;
    }
```

and jquery is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("licList:tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    });
```

I'm sure that the above jquery is not correct I've multiple tables in single page so I can't apply

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});
```

so my question is how to solve this problem????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> jquery is not correct I've multiple tables in single page so I can't
>   apply

Assign a `id/class` to your table and access rows under that table. Suppose your table has id tbl

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDgUc/)**

```
<table id="tbl">
   <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
   </tr> 
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tbl tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});
```

Comment: <table class="tbl">.....

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tbl tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});   is not working

Answer (score 3):

Remeber that jQuery selectors are just like CSS selectors so `licList:tr:odd` isn't a valid selector. You can do this with just CSS though:

```
.licList:nth-child(odd) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a Jquery selectors for both even rows and odd rows. You can use that with table id,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table1 tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#table1 tr:even").addClass("even");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 allow this , Dont go for javascript as you can easily do it

```
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#fff; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.fore6.com/samples/alternate_row_color/css3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `jQuery.each()` then it will be two collections of `table` and you can filter from there instead of a huge collection of `tr`

```
$('table').each(function(){
    $(this).find('tr').filter(':odd').addClass("odd"); //first rows always the same
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/rymvh/)